# Is this possible with Arduino? If yes than how?

Tags: arduino, switch-statement

I am making a ButtonBox for simulators with buttons, switches, potentionmeters etc. with Joystick library

The question is:

The loop is running repeatedly. For the first time, Pro Micro is reading HIGH value from DigitalPort.

Is it possible to run the code this way:
If the first loop is finished, the switch would turn off. 
If the second loop started, but the MC still reading HIGH values, the switch would turn off, but do not turn off till the value change to LOW. 
Like:

```
1st loop: HIGH->Turn on
2nd loop: HIGH->turn off
3rd loop:HIGH->still off etc... untill the value will be LOW.
```

Is this possible, if yes how?

Thank you for your help.

King Regards

Comment: action on button release? or button debounce?

Comment: Action on button.

Comment: action on button release? use a state variable `buttonPushed` to track the state and compare it with pin state

Comment: Re: " If the first loop is finished " You better think of an infinite number of loops in no time. (Eventually consider that a loop might take much less or even more than a millisecond) And yes, of course you can trigger actions for defined time periods independent of the trigger time.